# Shower Valve / Diverter pipe thread size

Tags: valve, pex

I am ordering my pex parts and am wondering what standard tub/shower valves use on the adapter. Male or female? 1/2" or 3/4" size?  I'd prefer a reputable brand but it looks like the adapters vary...

Answer (score 3):

(USA - likely different in places that use other thread forms, of course) The valve is **usually** 1/2" FIPT, so the PEX adapter you'd need would be a 1/2" MIPT (and at the showerhead end you'll want a PEX - 1/2" FIPT Drop Ear Elbow so you can affix the shower arm attachment to the framing.)

Of course, you could actually buy a particular shower valve and know for sure.